# Asynchronization between sliding animation and change of active bullet of pagination in Superslides

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dom-events

I use [Superslides](http://nicinabox.github.com/superslides/) to slide some content on my home page. The problem is that the sliding animation finish before the active bullet of pagination is changed. You can notice this in the demo [here](http://nicinabox.github.com/superslides/).

There is some delay between the start of the sliding animation and the change of the active bullet. Also, The same problem happen with firing the "slides.animated" event of the slider. I want this event to fire as soon as the sliding animation starts not after the sliding animation is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try ConversationJS to trigger both of them, or to call them one at a time.  It's so much easier to do dynamic stuff like this with an event based model: https://github.com/rhyneandrew/Conversation.JS